# Bootstrap + AngularJs Carousel

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4, carousel

I try to display my list of image in carousel. However, the images do not appear as I want.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
 <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" ng-repeat="movie in actionMovies">
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{{movie.image}}" alt="{{movie.name}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Use ng-src instead of src.

Comment: Actually, I haven't initialised the 'active' class. However, it will lead to another problem. That is all of the images float on the screen :(/